# What is the use of Delimiter in perl regex?

Tags: perl

What would be difference between these 2 lines of code

```
$bar="qwe. Aeiios qwe. Qwene. aqwet"
$bar=~/qwe/
```

and

```
$bar="qwe. Aeiios qwe. Qwene. aqwet"
    $bar=~m{qwe}
```

What difference does the delimiter make in the code? Both of them return true

Answer (score 4):

If your PATTERN includes `/` then `/PATTERN/` may not be able to work correctly, but `m{PATTERN}` will. Otherwise, there is no difference between them.

According to [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

> m/PATTERN/msixpodualgc
> /PATTERN/msixpodualgc
>
> If "/" is the delimiter then the initial m is optional. With the m you can use any pair of non-whitespace (ASCII) characters as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names that contain "/", to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome).

Comment: … where LTS is the horror that is escaping a path or an URL: `/\Ahttps?:\/\/example.com\/foo\/bar\//`. This looks so much cleaner with an alternate delimiter: `m{\A http[s]?://example.com/foo/bar/ }x`.